# How to use a dynamically bound variable between pages?

Tags: python, taipy

I have a Taipy application with several pages. Each page uses the "run()" method to scope the methods executed. Now, I want that one dynamically assigned State variable `state.some_id = "1234abcd"` is available in other pages too (to avoid that I have to re-implement the assignment again). If a state variable cannot be made available across pages, a common dynamically assigned variable `some_id = "1234abcd"` would also work. However, I could get it working.

I already tried experimenting with plain variables (not State variables) in **main**.py. These variables are available among all pages after the initial assignment, but it seems I cannot reassign them dynamically (e.g. via a on_change method).
The State variables, such as `state.some_id = "1234abcd"`, is not available in other pages - only in the page where I assign it via a control element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting a `run()` method in each file is unnecessary. You only need to put the Markdown string in the `Markdown` object.

The variables defined in the *main.py* can always be accessed in any functions and callbacks. It is not the case of variables defined in *page.py* inside the Markdown page (*value* in the example below). These can only be accessed through local callbacks that are being called from this page. The documentation for binding variables van be found [here](https://docs.taipy.io/en/latest/manuals/gui/binding/#scope-for-variable-binding).

Here, *value* can be accessed with the *change_value* callback (defined for the page). Another function not defined on this page cannot access it.

*global_value * is here in the Global Scope as I import it in my *main.py*. It can be accessed on every page. I can define callbacks associated to it in my *main.py*.

It is also possible to create visual elements in the root page to interact with *global_value*. Elements in the root page are present on each other page (like the navbar in this example, see the [doc](https://docs.taipy.io/en/latest/manuals/gui/pages/#single-page-applications) for more explanation).

*page.py*:

```py
from taipy.gui import Markdown

value = 10

global_value = 20

page_1_md = Markdown("""
<|{value}|slider|>

<|{global_value}|slider|>

<|Push|button|on_action=change_value|>
""")

def change_value(state):
    print("change value")
    state.value = 100
```

*main.py*:

I import the Markdown object of *page_1* to create my application. Don't forget to import *global_value* if you want to use it in different pages.

```py
from taipy.gui import Gui
from page_1 import page_1_md, global_value

pages = {
   "/":"<|navbar|>",
   "Page-1":page_1_md 
}

Gui(pages=pages).run()
```

Would you happen to have a simple example of what the issue is? Or would you like to suggest an improvement on this behaviour?

Comment: Sure, the idea is this. I have a selector on one page and use it so set a variable to a specific id (some_id in the example above). I want that this selection is no available to the other pages too because I don't want to re-implement the selector for each page.

If I use your example, the question is how I can make "value" available in a page_2_md (which is not in your example but could be added easily).

Comment: I edited my reply to answer your comment. I hope it answers it well